# Serialize root-level type differently than lower-level type

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is it possible in Json.NET to serialize a root-level type in the serialization hierarchy differently than a reference encountered at a lower level in the hierarchy?

For example, with this type

```
class Serialized {
  public Serialized Serialized;
  public int A;
}
```

in this setup

```
var serialized = new Serialized() { A = 1 };
var serialized2 = new Serialized() { A = 2 };
serialized.Serialized = serialized2;

string json = GetJson(serialized);
```

where json is

```
{
  "A":1
  "Serialized": {
    "ref":2
  }
}
```

Specifically, the root-level serialization should use the default serialization strategy and the lower-level ones should use a custom converter (or similar).

Comment: What about the property `Serialized` on nested objects? Should it be serialized or not?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define custom `JsonConverter` and decorate the `Serialized` property with it:

```
public class PropertyConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null) return;

        var serialized = (Serialized)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("ref");
        writer.WriteValue(serialized.A);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

And your class:

```
class Serialized {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyConverter))
    public Serialized Serialized;
    public int A;
}
```

This will work only for one level of nesting. If you need it to work of multiple nested levels, you need to modify the converter:

```
public class PropertyConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null) return;

        var serialized = (Serialized)value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("ref");
        writer.WriteValue(serialized.A);
        if(serialized.Serialized != null)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName("nested");
            writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serialized.Serialized, new JsonConverter[] {new PropertyConverter()}));
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to serialize without requiring a `[JsonConverter]` annotation? This is the current solution that I'm using, but one with less potential for error is preferable, ie, do everything directly in the converter.

Comment: Custom Serialization with `JSON.NET` is possible by creating custom converters that inherit from `JsonConverter` class. To use that converter you need to decorate your class or properties with it. (In your case is the property, because it is same type as the class and you want the default serialization for the top level object)